# SQLAlchemy and Falcon - session initialization

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, falconframework

I'm wondering where the best place would be to create a scoped session for use in falcon.

From reading the flask-sqlalchemy code, it, in a round about way, does something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

try:
    from greenlet import get_current as get_ident
except ImportError:
    try:
        from thread import get_ident
    except ImportError:
        from _thread import get_ident

connection_uri = 'postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/db'
engine = create_engine(connection_uri)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session_cls = scoped_session(session_factory, scopefunc=get_ident)
session = session_cls()
```

Would this work for falcon?  Will the `get_ident` func "do the right thing" when using gunicorn?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [middleware](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/middleware.html)

Example.

1. Create engine, session_factory and scoped_session object.

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine
   from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
   from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

   import settings


   engine = create_engine(
       '{engine}://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}'.format(
       **settings.POSTGRESQL
       )
   )

   session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
   ```
2. Create middleware.

   ```
   class SQLAlchemySessionManager:
       """
       Create a scoped session for every request and close it when the request
       ends.
       """

       def __init__(self, Session):
           self.Session = Session

       def process_resource(self, req, resp, resource, params):
           resource.session = self.Session()

       def process_response(self, req, resp, resource, req_succeeded):
           if hasattr(resource, 'session'):
               Session.remove()
   ```
3. Register middleware.

   ```
   import falcon


   app = falcon.API(middleware=[
       SQLAlchemySessionManager(Session),
   ])
   ```
4. Session is accessible in every request.

   ```
   import falcon


   class MyAPI:

       def on_get(self, req, resp):
           # You can access self.session here
           # self.session.add(foo)
           # self.session.commit()
   ```

Comment: This was really helpful. One quick question, should that be `resource.session.close()` or `resource.session.remove()`?

Comment: Neither, it should be `Session.remove()` according to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications.

Comment: Then should it not be `self.Session.remove()`?

Comment: How do you compare to https://eshlox.net/2019/05/28/integrate-sqlalchemy-with-falcon-framework-second-version/ ? Is there any rollback support integrated into remove method ? Edit: the close method seem to be using rollback under the hood https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a package on pypi, [falcon-sqla](https://pypi.org/project/falcon-sqla/), that provides a middleware to manage SQLAlchemy sessions with Falcon.

It uses the request context object to add a different session to each http request, avoiding the need to use a scoped session.